# Output HTML from ToString without using @Html.Raw

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a custom collection which holds messages for my view. I have overriden the `ToString` method so that it returns valid HTML. This allows it to be be easily referenced in the view.

```
@Model.Messages
```

Unfortunately the HTML is being encoded.

I know that for properties you can return an `IHtmlString` but that would require a wrapper property (something like `@Model.Messages.Render`) I also know that in the view I can use `@Html.Raw` to prevent the encoding but isn't there a way to inform the view that the `ToString` method returns a proper HTML string. Perhaps through data annotations?

I feel as though I'm having to add additional clutter to my view which I would rather encapsulate in my model.

Answer (score 2):

What about using [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Messages)
```